# How to define PLSQL table Type Based on Dynamic Cursor

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a requirement where as my number of columns in the cursor keeps on changing. so how to define the PLSQL table type based on Such kind of Dynamic cursors.

Thanks 
Vijay

Comment: Is your cursor defined as `CURSOR MY_CURSOR IS SELECT BLAH, BLAH2, BLAH3 FROM BLAH_TABLE WHERE BLAH = BLEH` or is the SELECT statement built up as a string and then opened into a SYS_REFCURSOR? Or are you doing something else? Please edit the question and include code which shows what you're doing. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can create a table at runtime based on your cursor, and then define your table type based on that temporary table using %rowtype .

Do not forget to drop that temporary table at the end of the program unit.

Comment: In Oracle creating and dropping tables run-time is almost always malpractice.